# Analytic Continuation of the incomplete gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, gamma-function

I have the following expression for $\alpha,z>0$:
\begin{equation}
\pi\mathrm i-\Gamma(\alpha)(-1)^\alpha\Gamma(1-\alpha,-z).
\end{equation}
In the context of the problem I am looking at this expression should be real-valued.  If we plot it as a function of $\alpha$, (I used $z=\pi$), we see that the imaginary part of the second term appears to be equal to $\pi\mathrm i$ (which it should be). If true, the imaginary terms cancel out and the value of the expression is real.

[image]

Is there any way I can use the analytic continuation of the incomplete gamma function to separate the real and imaginary parts of the second term?  I was able to do this for the case when $\alpha\in\Bbb N$ using [this identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/03/01/02/0009/). Put another way,  I am looking for the expression for
\begin{equation}
\Re\{\Gamma(\alpha)(-1)^\alpha\Gamma(1-\alpha,-z)\}
\end{equation}
when $\alpha,z>0$.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the imaginary part of the second term?

Comment: @Szeto I know that the imaginary part of the second term must be $\pi\mathrm i$.  I want to write the second term with its real and imaginary components separated so that I can cancel out the $\pi\mathrm i$'s.

Comment: @Szeto The reason why I want to do this is because when I do numerical evaluation, round-off error results in a small imaginary term being in the result even though the solution should always be real-valued.

Comment: Which branch of the incomplete gamma function did you choose? If you choose $$\Gamma(s,x)=x^s E_{1-s}(x)$$ and take the principal value, there could be no imaginary part at all!

Comment: @Szeto I have assumed the principal-valued branch cut.  There should be an imaginary part of $\pi\mathrm i$ as the plot in my post shows.  Unless I am mistaken, $E_{\nu}(-x)$ for $x>0$ should have a non zero imaginary component.

Comment: Well, $$E_n(-x)=\int^\infty_1\frac{e^{xt}}{t^n}dt$$ If you take the principal value, then the integrand is real, so as the integral. Also, $$(-z)^{1-a}(-1)^a$$ is real.

Comment: Here is an example calculation of $E_{1.1}(-1)$ which has the imaginary component. http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=En%281.1%2C-1%29.    I know the imaginary component had to be $\pi i$. I just need to find an expression for the real part of the second term. Maybe I am incorrect in the branch cut I thought I chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to provide the solution for
\begin{equation}
\Re\left\{(-z)^{\alpha-1}\Gamma(1-\alpha,-z)\right\}.
\end{equation}
All that is needed to get the solution for the original question is a bit of algebra.

---

Now, we have to evaluate the real component of the second term for the cases of $\alpha\in\Bbb N$ and $\alpha\notin\Bbb N$ separately.

Starting with the noninteger $\alpha$ case, we us [DLMF $8.7.3$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.7.E3) to rewrite the incomplete gamma term.  After a bunch of algebraic simplification we find
\begin{equation}
\Re\left\{(-z)^{\alpha-1}\Gamma(1-\alpha,-z)\right\}=%
-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!(1-\alpha+k)}%
-z^{\alpha-1}\Gamma(1-\alpha)\cos\pi\alpha.
\end{equation}
Then using $(1-\alpha+k)^{-1}=\frac{(1-\alpha)_k}{(1-\alpha)(2-\alpha)_k}$ we put the series term into the form of ${_1F_1}(a;b;z)$ to get

> \begin{equation}
> \Re\left\{(-z)^{\alpha-1}\Gamma(1-\alpha,-z)\right\}=%
> \frac{{_1F_1}(1-\alpha;2-\alpha;z)}{\alpha-1}%
> -z^{\alpha-1}\Gamma(1-\alpha)\cos\pi\alpha,\quad\alpha\notin\Bbb N.
> \end{equation}

For the integer $\alpha$ case we employ [this identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/06.06.03.0011.01) and note that $z>0$, $\log(-z)=\log z+\pi\mathrm i$. Again, with a good amount of algebraic simplification we find

> \begin{equation}
> \Re\left\{(-z)^{\alpha-1}\Gamma(1-\alpha,-z)\right\}=%
> \frac{z^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}%
> \left(%
> e^{z}\sum_{k=0}^{\alpha-2}\frac{k!}{z^{k+1}}%
> -\operatorname{Ei}(z)%
> \right),\quad \alpha\in\Bbb N.
> \end{equation}